# problem using Python to increase virtual memory for my java application

Tags: python

I have created a java application in Eclipse which when I increase the VM arguments to -Xmx1024m runs fine. When I try to run the application via the command promt using the following path:

c:\python27\python c:\jars2run\run.py c:\jars2run\myown\ClassTree.jar LiveSimulator2/Live_PairsEngine3 java -Xmx1024m

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.dec… Source)
at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getStringIntern…
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(Resul…
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(Resul…
at LiveSimulator2.Timeseries2.<init>(Timese…
at LiveSimulator2.Live_PairsEngine3.main(Li…
```

I have found out that I need to add the heap memory requirement in the python script but cannot figure out where in the scipt I have to put the 'java -Xmx1024m' or what ever is needed and therefore the java application still falls over due to lack of memory.

See below for the python script, at the moment the python script just copies the external jars need to run my java application.

```
import sys
import os

classfile=sys.argv[2];
jar=sys.argv[1];
cp='%s' % jar
FILES=os.listdir('c:/jars2run/3rdparty');
os.chdir('c:/jars2run/3rdparty');
for i in FILES:
    if (i.endswith('jar')):
        cp='%s;%s' % (cp, i)

cmd='java -classpath "%s" %s' % (cp, classfile)
print('%s' % cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

Could someone let me know where the memory increase needs to should go please.

Very grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
cmd='java -classpath "%s" %s' % (cp, classfile)
```

to

```
cmd='java -Xmx1024m -classpath "%s" %s' % (cp, classfile)
```

BTW: some pointers on Python:

1. You don't need semicolons on the ends of lines, and you don't need to wrap the `if` condition in parentheses.
2. If your format string is only `"%s"`, then you aren't gaining anything by formatting, just use the string as is.
3. You can append to a string with `+=`.
4. The Python stdlib includes the `glob` module for finding files with shell wildcard patterns.

Using these (and a few others), we can clean up your script:

```
import sys
import os
import glob

cp = sys.argv[1]
classfile = sys.argv[2]
os.chdir('c:/jars2run/3rdparty')
for f in glob.glob("*.jar"):
    cp += ';%s' % f

cmd = 'java -classpath "%s" %s' % (cp, classfile)
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Yes. Explanation for the person who asked the question: Command-line arguments do not carry over from one program to another, unless you explicitly write code to do so. (However, environment variables generally do carry over - but again, it depends on how you code it - you can choose not to carry them over.)